# Always disable tabbed conversations in Lync 2013

Tags: registry, settings, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

Is there any way by which i can make sure that the user uses the initial settings of the lync client,i.e, the  tools->options should not be available to the user so that he/she cannot change any thing in lync and use the default setting.The use case for which i want this is that i want all the conversations to be un-tabbed. I make the registry key "IsTabbedConversationWindowEnabled_1" 0 for this but it is overridden if the user goes through tools->options in lync ui and enables tabbed conversation. I also set only read permission for this key but the conversations are still tabbed. So how can i achieve this? If the question is not clear do tell, i will be happy to enhance it and provide more details

Thanks

Comment: you will need to make a custom lync application to hide Tools->Options , as there is no addins sopported for Lync so we cant change any thing in it like Outlook or any other Office Applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could export that registry key to a .reg file, and then simply "run" that .reg file each time you want to fix it.

I have a similar bug (can't drag files into VLCPlayer sometimes) that I have to fix via the same process - a .reg file that I just run.

I'd do this myself, but your question doesn't say *where* in the registry to add the key you mention. I'd love to automate a fix to this :)